# is reading XElement value using c# extension method thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net

In Multi threaded environment is this extension method thread safe ?

```
class Program
{
    public static object lockObject = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> studentCollection = new List<Student>();

        string xml = "<root>";
        xml += "<student><name>stud1</name><address>street1</address></student>";
        xml += "<student><name>stud2</name><address>street2</address></student>";
        xml += "<student><name>stud3</name><address>street3</address></student>";
        xml += "</root>";

        Parallel.For(0, 10000, index =>
        {
            XElement xmlElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var students = xmlElement.Descendants("student").ToList();
            students.ForEach(student =>
            {
                Student stud = new Student();
                stud.Name = student.GetValue("name");
                stud.Address = student.GetValue("address");
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    studentCollection.Add(stud);
                }

            });

        });
    }    
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static string GetValue(this XElement xelement, string tagName)
    {
        var ele = xelement;

        if (ele != null && ele.Element(tagName) != null)
        {
            // I assume this as unsafe code. 
            return ele.Element(tagName).Value;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not?

Comment: If xelement can change, then no. If it cannot, then yes. To make both cases thread-safe, save the ele.Element(tagName) into variable and use that.

Comment: To expand on Euphoric's comment, if using C#6, the method can be rewritten as:
`return ele?.Element(tagName)?.Value ?? string.Empty;`
which is thread safe also (in the sense that the `?.` operator stores its operand in a temporary variable before the null check and usage, like your code does)

Comment: @DavidE - an XElement is a mutable reference type. Storing a copy of the reference won't do much.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was referring to `ele.Element(tagName)`, which could become null between its check and use. (So sure, the first `?.` doesn't add to the thread safety, but the second one does, I believe?)

Comment: @user2843663 - why do you want it to be thread-safe? This can only be answered in the context of some usage pattern.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is correct, the OP doesn't offer a usage, so we're talking about the definition of a static function that doesn't rely on static variables..  "why do you think it's not" to coin Rahul

Comment: XElement is not thread-safe.  You can't make it more unsafe.

Comment: It is meaningless to just as whether something is "thread safe". It only makes sense if you ask about *from what scenarios*. So: what scenarios do you need it to be thread-safe against?

Comment: i have updated the question with scenerio

Comment: Bricks are solid. Houses are made from bricks. Therefore houses are solid. WRONG! All my XML calls are thread-safe. My method is made from my XML calls. Therefore my method is thread-safe. WRONG!

Answer (score 3):

Your extension method is inherently thread safe because it does not modify the state of its object*.

It doesn't call any methods or set any properties on any arguments passed to it that could change their state. If it did, you could still consider it thread safe. The question would be whether the methods and properties on those other objects was thread safe.

It sounds like you're really asking whether the properties of `XElement` are thread safe. They are not. You can't safely do concurrent updates and reads to its properties. But again, that's `XElement`, not your extension method.

If there's the possibility that multiple threads might attempt unsafe read/writes on an object then you'd need to use a `lock` or some other mechanism to control access to the object. Once you've passed that object to another method, there's nothing that method can do unless it has a way of performing a 100% guaranteed atomic operation.

I wouldn't recommend getting into any details of how some particular line of code compiles to determine what is or is not atomic. If it's something like `Interlocked.Increment` that exists *for that purpose*, great. Or if it's something like reading a `Boolean` where it's explicitly documented that it's atomic. Other than that, I would just protect the object from access by multiple threads.

I'm *guessing* that you're just reading the XML which would make this a moot point. If you were building these elements then you would already know the value and wouldn't need to read it from the XML at the same time as you're modifying it. Just guessing.

---

For clarity, here's an example of an extension method that's *not* thread safe.

```
public static class StringTrimExtensions
{
     public static int CharactersTrimmed {get; private set;}

     public static string Trim(this string input)
     {
         var trimmed = input.Trim();
         CharactersTrimmed = CharactersTrimmed + (input.Length - trimmed.Length);
         return trimmed;
     }
}
```

(It's a totally useless method.) But it's not thread safe because it's modifying its own state in a non-thread safe way. So if it's used from multiple threads then the count of trimmed characters could get corrupted.

But if we change it to ensure that the update to the total is atomic, then the method becomes thread safe.

```
public static class StringTrimExtensions
{
    private static int _charactersTrimmed;
    public static int CharactersTrimmed { get {return _charactersTrimmed;}  }

    public static string Trim(this string input)
    {
        var trimmed = input.Trim();
        var countOfTrimmedCharacters = input.Length - trimmed.Length;
        Interlocked.Add(ref _charactersTrimmed, countOfTrimmedCharacters);
        return trimmed;
    }
}
```

Or, for the sake of demonstration, we could use a `lock` to prevent multiple threads from concurrently updating `CharactersTrimmed`. (If we're just adding numbers like this then `Interlocked` makes more sense.)

```
public static class StringTrimExtensions
{
    public static int CharactersTrimmed { get; private set; }
    private static readonly object CharactersTrimmedLock = new object();

    public static string Trim(this string input)
    {
        var trimmed = input.Trim();
        lock (CharactersTrimmedLock)
        {
            CharactersTrimmed += (input.Length - trimmed.Length);
        }
        return trimmed;
    }
}
```

But either way, whether we prevent the unsafe operation using `Interlocked` or `lock`, we've made the method thread safe.

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure where you've determined properties on XElement to be concurrent.. reviewing the type indicates "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe." ..

Comment: From the same documentation you're quoting. `Element` is not a *static* method of `XElement`, and `Name` is not a static property.